# Querying model data in form for cleaned DB

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

So I have forms.py which is as below:

```
from django import forms
from .models import SipExtension
from xmpp.models import xmpp_buddy_groups

class ExtensionForm(forms.Form):
    xmpp_buddy_groups_choices = xmpp_buddy_groups.objects.values_list('group_name',flat=True)


    boolean_choices=(('Yes','Yes'),('No','No'))
    sip_extension = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0,max_value=100000)
    sip_secret = forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=32)
    commlink_push = forms.ChoiceField(choices=boolean_choices,widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,required=True)
    real_name = forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=32)
    xmpp = forms.ChoiceField(choices=boolean_choices,widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,required=True)
    xmpp_username = forms.CharField(required = True,min_length=5)
    xmpp_password = forms.CharField(max_length=32, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    xmpp_buddy_groups_names = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=xmpp_buddy_groups_choices,widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,required=False)
```

It works fine if my DB is already created by previous migrations. But I faced problem when my DB is blank. To test,I dropped all the tables and then run make migrations and got below error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "extensions_sipextension" does not exist
LINE 1: ...p_buddy_groups_names"."xmpp_buddy_groups_id" FROM "extension...
```

I am getting problems in handling this on blank database when I need to deploy on entirely new system. I could handle that by commenting the urls which are executing views which needs this form but that is a bad and temporary work around. How to fix this?

Comment: You need to clear the files in migrations folder

Comment: In entirely new system there is nothing in migrations folder already.

Comment: @sakthiselvam please don't recommend this, it is almost never the right idea. But deosha, that should absolutely not be the case; your new system should have the migrations already created since they are part of the code base.

Comment: Sure @DanielRoseman

Comment: @DanielRoseman We are taking care of that no migration scripts are there on entirely new system. and Yes, in production system we cannot delete migrations if system is not new.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with `xmpp_buddy_groups_choices` attribute in the form. The queryset is evaluated at time of project load. So when you are using `./manage.py makemigrations`, the `xmpp_buddy_groups_choices` trying to evaluate the queryset, but failed as there is no table in database. Try to wrap the choices in a function and pass that function in the `choices` parameter.

And your `choices` is required to be a list of tuples (with 2 elements), but the `xmpp_buddy_groups_choices` is a list of strings.

Sample Code:

```
class ExtensionForm(forms.Form):
    @staticmethod
    def get_group_choices():
        xmpp_buddy_groups_choices = xmpp_buddy_groups.objects.values_list('group_name',flat=True)
        return xmpp_buddy_groups_choices


    boolean_choices=(('Yes','Yes'),('No','No'))
    sip_extension = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0,max_value=100000)
    sip_secret = forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=32)
    commlink_push = forms.ChoiceField(choices=boolean_choices,widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,required=True)
    real_name = forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=32)
    xmpp = forms.ChoiceField(choices=boolean_choices,widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,required=True)
    xmpp_username = forms.CharField(required = True,min_length=5)
    xmpp_password = forms.CharField(max_length=32, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    xmpp_buddy_groups_names = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=ExtensionForm.get_group_choices,widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,required=False)
```

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by passing the function to choices parameter? Can you give an example? Also, it works fine when tables are there so there is no problem with choices parameter.

Comment: @deosha: Edited the answer.